# Add extra price to subtotal in magento

Tags: php, magento

I wanted to add extra fix price for each item in the cart. I've found a solution from google and I follow that instruction and got it work. But now it's not working, here is the code that I followed..

**path - /app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php**

```
protected function _totalBaseCalculation($item, $request)
    {
        $calc   = $this->_calculator;
        $request->setProductClassId($item->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
        $rate   = $calc->getRate($request);
        $qty    = $item->getTotalQty();

        $price          = $taxPrice         = $item->getCalculationPriceOriginal();
        $basePrice      = $baseTaxPrice     = $item->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal();
        $subtotal       = $taxSubtotal      = $item->getRowTotal()+25;
        $baseSubtotal   = $baseTaxSubtotal  = $item->getBaseRowTotal()+25;



        $taxOnOrigPrice = !$this->_helper->applyTaxOnCustomPrice($this->_store) && $item->hasCustomPrice();
        if ($taxOnOrigPrice) {
            $origSubtotal       = $item->getOriginalPrice() * $qty;
            $baseOrigSubtotal   = $item->getBaseOriginalPrice() * $qty;
        }
```

I have changed  this two line

```
    $subtotal       = $taxSubtotal      = $item->getRowTotal()+25;
    $baseSubtotal   = $baseTaxSubtotal  = $item->getBaseRowTotal()+25;
```

can you please help me.....

Comment: why would you even do that? it's very obvious.. users will notice the difference.. :D

Comment: I wanted to add extra fix price for each item in the cart.I don't know how

Comment: users know that extra price will be added to their products. We have advertised on our website